# Is the chromebook Linux based at its core?

Tags: linux, chrome

Just wondering if the Chromebook uses Linux in some way? If so, would there be a way to run Linux commands (e.g. Ssh) from a command line on it?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it does use the Linux *kernel*.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_OS

Since the kernel is arguably all that can strictly be called "Linux", the complete OS that we all know and love is more properly called "GNU/Linux".  The "GNU" part provides the fundamentals of the *userspace* (as opposed to *kernelspace*) and without that, there is no guarantee at all about what software can be used, since software applications exist in userspace, not kernelspace.

Phorce's first link looks pretty decisive tho, so ssh is good.  Just don't take the fact that the linux kernel is used to mean it is anything like e.g., Ubuntu, anymore than Android (which also uses the Linux kernel) is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Chromebook does allow SSH.

[check this link](http://www.chromebookforum.com/forum/17-chrome-os-software-forum/390-ssh-built.html)

Also, I think they just pack in ChromeOS (Which I believe is an operating system based upon being online. However, you can install Linux.

[Check this link](http://hardware.slashdot.org/story/12/11/20/1617210/250-chromebook-with-ubuntu-linux-is-very-fast)

Comment: Don't just post links. Please summarize the information found in the links in the case they become dead.

Comment: Apologies for just posting links. Refer to @goldilocks post for further, more in-depth reply.

Comment: SSH was just an example.  A more detailed list of what *is* included—or at least some more examples—would be useful, and perhaps also some examples of what is *not* included.